# Does $argv behave the same between Centos and RHEL systems

Tags: session, tcl, centos7, argv, rhel6

I am trying to troubleshoot an old TCL accounting script called GOTS - Grant Of The System.  What it does is creates a time stamped logfile entry for each user login and another for the logout.  The problem is it is not creating the second log file entry on logout.  I think I tracked down the area where it is going wrong and I have attached it here. FYI the log file exists and it does not exit with the error "GOTS was called incorrectly!!". It should be executing the `if then` for `[string match "$argv" "end_session"]`

This software runs properly on RHEL Linux 6.9 but fails as described on Centos 7.  I am thinking that there is a system variable or difference in the `$argv` argument vector for the different systems that creates this behavior.

Am I correct in suspecting `$argv` and if not does anyone see the true problem?

How do I print or display the $argv values on logout?

```
# Find out if we're beginning or ending a session
if { [string match "$argv" "end_session"] } {
    if { ![file writable $Log] } {
    onErrorNotify "4 LOG"
    }
    set ifd [open $Log a]
    puts $ifd "[clock format [clock seconds]]\t$Instrument\t$LogName\t$GroupName"
    close $ifd
    unset ifd
    exit 0
} elseif { [string match "$argv" "begin_session"] == 0 } {
    puts stderr "GOTS was called incorrectly!!"
    exit -1
}
```

end_session is populated by the /etc/gdm/PostSession/Default file

```html
#!/bin/sh


### Begin GOTS PostSession
#  Do not run GOTS if root is logging out
if test "${USER}" == "root" ; then
    exit 0
fi

/usr/local/lib/GOTS/gots end_session > /var/tmp/gots_postsession.log 2> /var/tmp/gots_postsession.log
exit 0
### End GOTS PostSession
```

This is the postsession log file:

```html
Application initialization failed: couldn't connect to display ":1"
Error in startup script: invalid command name "option"
    while executing
"option add *Font "-adobe-new century schoolbook-medium-r-*-*-*-140-*-*-*-*-*-*""
    (file "/usr/local/lib/GOTS/gots" line 26)
```

After a lot of troubleshooting we have determined that for whatever reason Centos is not allowing part of the /etc/gdm/PostSession/default file to execute:

fi

```
/usr/local/lib/GOTS/gots end_session
```

But it does update the PostSession.log file as it should .. . Does anyone have any idea what could be interfering with only part of the PostSession/default?

Comment: This doesn't look like perl to me. Can you show the shebang line please.

Comment: Looks like TCL .

Comment: Should I post the entire 417 lines of code or is that asking too much? Yes it is TCL.  I'll edit my question.

Comment: I just edited it for you. The first thing I'd try is to print the value of `$argv` and see whether it's what you expected. Posting the entire 417 lines would indeed be too much. If possible narrow it down to a small program that illustrates the problem, a [mcve] (follow that link).

Comment: It's pretty unlikely that `argv` is handled differently on different linux platforms. Are you calling the script in an identical way on each platform, or could each platform have it's own script that eventually calls your tcl script? Please show how your script is being called.

Comment: Bryan - The program is loaded on bootup and was installed using a shell script that ascertains whether tk is installed and populates the required files and insalls GOTS.  Keith - I'm not sure I can get this snippet to run by itself.

Comment: _Interesting…_ It's using `string match` to check equality of a list (`argv` gets set to the list of command line arguments after the script being executed) against a string.

Comment: Donal Fellows - Is it possible that Centos has a slightly different end session string in argv where it falls through such as "End session", "end session", "End_session" or "End_Session" ???

Comment: Why don't you just look at the value of `argv` just before the `if`-`elseif` block: `puts ARGV=$argv; if {[string match ...]} { ... } `. You would also have to tell how the the script is called exactly and, therefore, populates `argv`.

Comment: Are you really sure that the script is called on logout? How is it actually executed on logout? What's the mechanism?

Comment: Flopp - see the edits in the question.

Comment: @Donal Fellows The bounty has yet to be awarded since I don't have an answer that works yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that our script has certain elements that depend upon the Xserver running on logout to display some of the GUI error messages.  This from:

[Gnome Configuration](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en#scripting)

"When a user terminates their session, GDM will run the PostSession script. Note that the Xserver will have been stopped by the time this script is run, so it should not be accessed.

Note that the PostSession script will be run even when the display fails to respond due to an I/O error or similar. Thus, there is no guarantee that X applications will work during script execution."

We are having to rewrite those error message callouts so they simply write the errors to a file instead of depending on the display.  The errors are for things that should be there in the beginning anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone have any idea what could be interfereing with PostSession/default?

Could it be that you are hitting [Bug 851769](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=851769)?

That said, am I correct in stating that, as your investigation shows, this is not a Tcl-related issue or question anymore?

Comment: Very interesting ... we did use xrandr to specify display mirroring!